# Start Service within other service not start

Tags: java, android

I want to start one service from other service not in an activity, I did following code, but not work it execute block but service not started.

**Myservice.class**

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constant1.URL_GET_COURSE_LIST);
String result = HTTPadapter.getDetails(post);
Log.e("resultofcourselist", "" + result);
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DemoService.class);
i.putExtra("result", result);
startService(i);
```

**Demoservice.class**

```
intent.getStringExtra("result");

try {
    jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);
    jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0);
    jsonMainNode = jsonObject.optJSONArray("rowsResponse");

    //DbAdd dbAdd=new DbAdd();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        result = jsonChildNode.optString("result").toString();

        if (result.equals("Success")) {
            jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(1);
            jsonMainNode = jsonObject.optJSONArray("getCourseList");
            // dbAdd.setJsonMainNode(jsonMainNode);
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonMainNode.length(); j++) {
                // dbAdd.setJsonChildNode();
                JSONObject childnode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(j);
                Intent dbadd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dbadd.class);
                dbadd.putExtra("mainnode", jsonMainNode.toString());
                dbadd.putExtra("childnode", childnode.toString());
                // dbadd.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startService(dbadd);
            }
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".Myservice" />
<service android:name=".DemoService" />
```

**Log**

```
Myservice start print in log but in demoservice on startcommand not execute
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove following line because after starting service you suddenly calling `stopSelf()` which stops the service

```
stopSelf();
```

Comment: @martin Demoservice never start through my service that's my problem

Comment: @user3481301 the answer has been edited, thus making my comment (and yours aswell) obsolete ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent Service. You don't need to stop Intent Service. It will automatically stop after the Task is completed.

How to make Intent Service Class:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
private static final String TAG = "MyIS";
private Context mContext;
public MyIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
    mContext = this;}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Do Your Code Here.
}}
```

And don't forget to Register in Manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyIntentService "
        android:exported="false" />
```

Start the Intent Service from Async using Context You Get: // I use mContext

```
        Intent intent_update = new Intent(mContext, MyIntentService .class);
    mContext.startService(intent_update);
```

Need More help then Comment.

Comment: i got mcontext , but intentservice is also child of context , so its not need to mcontext

Comment: Actually I started Intent Service from AsyncTask so I wrote that. Sry for that.